# Hull-White-1F swaption price Parameters using tf_quant_finance

Tags: programming, interest-rate-swap

Sorry for this rather general question but im new in this field.
I'm asked to model the Expected Expsoure of an interest rate swap.
The Short Rate should be modelled via a 1factor Hull-White model:
$dr(t)=\left(\theta(t)-a\cdot r(t)\right) dt + \sigma(t) dW(t)$

I'm trying to price the swap with tf_quant_finance.models.hull_white.swaption_price [Link to the Documentation](https://github.com/google/tf-quant-finance/blob/master/api_docs/tf_quant_finance/models/hull_white/swaption_price.md)

My problem is I do not understand all the parameters:

- expiries: this should be the the duration of the swap
- floating_leg_start_times: i have no idea what this is
- floating_leg_end_times: i have no idea what this is
- fixed_leg_payment_times: this should be the dates on which the fixed payment is due
- floating_leg_daycount_fractions: i have no idea what this is
- fixed_leg_daycount_fractions: i have no idea what this is
- fixed_leg_coupon: this should be the fixed interest rate
- reference_rate_fn: i only have the zero rate for a finite set of timestamps, so my question would be how to approximate this the best

for the rest of the parameters i know what they are for (or at least what value they have and how i have to use them)

Sorry for asking about some of these basic terms but im not fluent in english (especially not in finace english)

Comment: Do you want to price swaption or swap? The function you are using is for Swaptions but you are asking about exposure for swap? Swap has two legs and each leg has its own payment schedule with its properties like day count fractions, start times, end times etc.

Comment: @emot I want to price a swap (interest rate swap) which has multiple payments a year (on fixed dates) for a fixed number of years